# How to refreseh keycloak user token from the refresh token in java

Tags: java, keycloak, refresh-token

Due to the architecture of our product, the loadbalancer that I use is not able to manage correctly my servers. To solve this point, I have create a kind of manager which forward the call to the correct server by requesting it directly from the first server when it is needed. The issue is to do that I forward the user keycloak token string in the header of the second call. It works pretty well but after few minutes to token is invalidate. I tried to refresh it by many way without success. I have 2 constraints. I can't reask the credentials to the user, and I can't use the keycloak secret because I'm working in a multi tenant / multi realm app. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have just the access_token on login.

1. First you need to exchange that access token for a refresh token (and another access token), you do this by calling:

```
HTTP POST {{host}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token
HEADERS:
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
BODY:
 grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange
 subject_token: the_user_access_token
 client_id: your_client_id (in my case this is "public")
 requested_token_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token
```

2. you will get back a response that looks like this:

```
{
    "access_token": "access_token_value",
    "expires_in": access_token_time_in_seconds,
    "refresh_expires_in": refresh_token_time_in_seconds,
    "refresh_token": "refresh_token_value",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    ...
}
```

3. So with this you have what you need to actually refresh your token with the following request:

```
HTTP POST {{host}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token
HEADERS:
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
BODY:
 grant_type: refresh_token
 refresh_token: refresh_token_value
 client_id: public
```

4. This will get you the following response:

```
{
    "access_token": "access_token_value",
    "expires_in": access_token_time_in_seconds,
    "refresh_expires_in": refresh_token_time_in_seconds,
    "refresh_token": "refresh_token_value",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    ...
}
```

Now you can repeat step 3 and 4 up until the maximum session duration.

Comment: Thanks @Dharman. I Have progress on my issue and in fact the way I did it was good. The really issue in fact is the deployment object which should be in my refreshTokenSecurityContext is null when the request come from my angular GUI. And without this information, it s not possible to refresh the token. I have tried your solution but with this way I can't propagate this new token because I have not got access to a setter to override the first one provide by the authentication façade.